# remove an arbitrary element from a nest of lists and dicts in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested

```
a = [ 
    {
        'b':[1,2,3]
    },{
        'c':{
            'd':'e',
            'f':'g'
        }
    } 
]
b = [0,'b',2]
c = [2,'c','f']
```

In the above, I want to use the keys contained in `b` or `c` to destroy the corresponding element in `a`. In this case, `del a[1]['b'][2]` for `a`, or `a[2]['c'].pop('f')` for `c`.

Is there a clean way to do this given an arbitrary depth and tree structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def nested_del(structure, del_spec):
    for item in del_spec[:-1]:  # Loop through all but the last element.
        structure = structure[item]  # Go further into the nested structure
    del structure[del_spec[-1]]  # Use the last element to delete the desired value

nested_del(a, b)
nested_del(a, c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I think that only works for lists, not dictionaries. Your code returns 'KeyError b' on `structure = structure[item]` on the first loop, and I'm also not sure `del` works on dictionaries.

Comment: The reason for the error is because `b` should be `[0,'b',2]`. I just tested this and `del` does work on dictionaries.

Comment: Rock on, Skyler. Thanks so much. That did it.

Comment: Glad it helped! Have fun coding :)